# EclipseLink : No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: jpa, eclipse-plugin, playframework, eclipselink

I am trying to develop a web application. I started creating a Play! Framework project in Eclipse. 
For the model part I chose to use JPA and since I had already created the database I was searching a way auto-generate the model classes. 
I converted it to faceted form and used [Dali](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/) to create the mapping with the database. During the configuration I was promted to chose a JPA implementation so I chose EclipseLink 2.1.3 Helios as a user library. 
All the jars where added in my project.
After searching for similar errors, I modified the persistence.xml to:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="StudentApplication">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>models.Grade</class>
        <class>models.GradePK</class>
        <class>models.Student</class>
                <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentapplication"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The exact error I am getting now is:
Execution exception (In /app/controllers/class.java around line 98)
PersistenceException occured : No Persistence provider for EntityManager named jpa

I have to note that in application.conf I have declared the db connection and when I run the application I get

> 22:03:53,084 INFO  ~ Connected to jdbc:mysql://localhost/studentapplication?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci

Finally the file structure is:

-controllers
 -models
 -views
 -META-INF
          |_persistense.xml

As you may have understood (besides my rep) I am a newbie in web application development and specifically in JPA. I would be more than grateful to any kind of help. I apologize in advance if I posted not-needed information or if I missed mandatory information. Thank you for your time.

Thomas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are referencing the persistence unit in your application by a different name than in your *persistence.xml*. Your persistence unit is named "StudentApplication" in *persistence.xml*. However, the error states that it is named "jpa" in your application.

Assuming that you are using application managed entity manager, there must be a line like this in your app:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpa");
```

Change it to

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("StudentApplication");
```

Comment: Matt, I dont know how to thank you. You made a man somewhere in a small island in the Meditteranean feel really,really stupid and really,really happy at the same time. Thank you.

Comment: Let me cheer you up by the fact that the weather in your region is currently much more pleasant than here at the baltic sea. You are welcome!